# How to add Gitlab custom variable in app.config xml file

Tags: c#, xml, gitlab, gitlab-ci, app-config

I'm working on C# project using Gitlab CI and would like to hide secrets in app.config file.

I added one variable in Gitlab and in app.config like this:

```
<add key="User" value="username" />
<add key="Password" value=$Password />
```

Then, when i try to build application in gitlab CI using msbuild, i receive an error:

> $ msbuild "$PROJECTNAME.sln" /consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly /t:Test_project /maxcpucount /nologo /property:Configuration=Release /verbosity:quiet
>   app.config(5,33): error MSB3249: Application Configuration file "app.config" is invalid. '$' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 7, position 33. [/builds/project/Test_project/Test_project.Service/Test_project.Service.csproj]

Please advice, how to add Gitlab environment variable in app.config xml file.

Comment: There should be quotes around the attribute value, which is what the error message is telling you - *expected token is " or '*.

Comment: @CharlesMager, if add a quotes around the attribute value it will be just text, not the value of variable:

`<add key="Password" value="$Password" />`

cat ./Test_project.Service/bin/Release/Test_project.Service.exe.config

...
`<add key="Password" value="$Password" />`
...

`echo $Password

password`

Comment: Ah, ok - I've slightly missed the point here! I'm not sure I know enough about how Gitlab does this to comment, though the end result would still need quotes around it. Given it complains about the `$` it would seem it's not being replaced at all.

Comment: Did you try using `value="%Password%"` ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster, yes, result is a text, like in previous comment: 

`<add key="Password" value="%Password%" />`

Comment: Could you add in the question how do you add variable in Gitlab ? Is It a variable in CI/CD ? or directly in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster i added variable in the setting of my project: 

`(Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables)`

Comment: @archibald95 : I am also facing similar issue to get gitlab var value into web config.Did u able to find its solution? Please share if you have.

Comment: Check this alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77370551/9399171

Answer (score 1):

For .xml files it should work using **${env.MY_VAR_DEFINED_IN_GITLAB}**

Where MY_VAR_DEFINED_IN_GITLAB, as specified, is the variable defined in Gitlab Project (or group) -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables

Therefore in your case should work:

```
<add key="User" value=${env.GITLAB_VAR_USERNAME}/>
<add key="Password" value=${env.GITLAB_VAR_PASSWORD}/>
```